# Connect to remote kernel on AWS using local qtconsole?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

By following the instructions listed here:

Running a notebook server — IPython 1.2.1: An Afternoon Hack documentation - https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.1.0/interactive/public_server.html

I have been able to connect to a remote notebook server on Amazon AWS via the browser. Can I get to this kernel using   a local qtconsole?  In other words, can I do something like this on the local client:

% ipython qtconsole --kernel

My concern is that the instructions listed above refer to a password and certificate that is required by the browser to connect to the remote server. How would this work with the desired qtconsole? Maybe some kind of tunnel is required to handle this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In addition to this excellent post, please note that by typing `%connect_info` in the notebook, you get the name and content of the JSON file. You can create a local file from this content without having to retrieve it on the distant machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me awhile to figure out so I thought I'd save others the trouble. The link

http://jupyter.org/qtconsole/stable/#ssh-tunnels

provides some clues but is incomplete. Note that I am interested in connecting a local ipython qtconsole to a remote kernel. The first thing is to start the
console on the remote machine by doing

```
% ipython console
```

This fires up a ipython console on the amazon instance. Next, I manually
transfer the `kernel-*.json` file to my local machine. This file is automatically created in the `.ipython/profile_default/security` directory on the remote instance. Note that by `kernel-*.json`, I mean the kernel file that is created automatically when `ipython console` is run. Usually, this looks something like `kernel-21311.json`, for example. It is possible to configure this with the `.ipython` configuration files, but that's another story.

```
# filename: console_tunnels.py
import json
import argparse
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from time import sleep

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('ipython_json',
                        type=str,
                        help='ipython kernel json file')
    parser.add_argument('--host',
                        type=str,
                        help='hostname',
                        default='awsinstance')
    parser.add_argument('-k',
                        '--private_key',
                        type=str,
                        help='private_key',
                        default='/home/reckoner/.ssh/id_rsa')
    parser.add_argument('-u',
                        '--username',
                        type=str,
                        help='username',
                        default='reckoner')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    ports_keys = ['stdin_port', 'control_port', 'hb_port', 'shell_port',
                  'iopub_port']
    d = json.load(open(args.ipython_json))
    addresses = [('127.0.0.1', d[i]) for i in ports_keys]

    with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ssh_username=args.username,
        local_bind_addresses=addresses,
        remote_bind_addresses=addresses,
        ssh_private_key=args.private_key,
        ssh_address=args.host, ):
        while True:
            # press Ctrl-C for stopping
            sleep(0.5)
```

Next, I run the script listed above on the client machine

```
% python console_tunnels.py kernel-*.json
```

and then all the right ports get forwarded!

The next step is to start the local qtconsole by pointing it to the
kernel-*.json file I downloaded earlier.

```
% ipython qtconsole --existing kernel-*.json
```

and that's it! You can now work in the qtconsole but all the computation
happens on the remote instance. The great part is that opening figure windows in the qtconsole opens them on the **client** while the data and computation reside on the remote instance!

Enjoy!

Comment: I am not able to find kernel-*.json in .ipython/profile_default/security. Any idea what could be happening?

Comment: @Shahensha They may have changed its location to "/run/user<user id>/jupyter/".You can use strace to see which files a program writes to disk. I've used "strace ipython kernel &> strace.out" and then by grepping this file found that it opened "/run/user/1012/jupyter/kernel-27216.json" for writing. 1012 is my uid on the machine (visible by running "id").

Comment: Thank you so much @AmitMoscovichEiger

Comment: You can get the json file also by running
%connect_info 
in the python console on the remote server.
This will print the json file, then just copy-paste it to a local file